# How to set a debug log to trace the process of the Custom URL order form in Sites

Tags: debugging, debug

Hi There is a exception Iam getting in the Online order form while submitting it throws the common error for all users, It seems to be an Exception, However I tried to set a Debug logs to trace it but it did not captured.

Can anyone provide your thoughts on this.

[image]

this is the common error, however it is a custom URL which can access by anyone and no Registration or log in is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup the debug on the site guest user. So:

1. Got to Setup
2. then Debug logs
3. Click New, search "site"

You may get multiple results if you have more than one site. Then pick the site user matching the name of the site you are debugging.

So if I had a site called `helpme` then the user to debug would be called `helpme guest site user`.